# Ubuntu boot entry missing after installing Windows 11

Tags: windows, dual-boot, boot-loader, kubuntu

I recently decided that I wanted to try out Windows 11 on my laptop that was running Windows 10, but it's a bit of an older laptop so the hardware isn't supported by Windows 11 and I had to do a clean install. My main OS on this laptop however, is Kubuntu 20.04. One of the reasons to reinstall Windows is so that I could claim some extra space for Ubuntu. I removed all Windows partitions from Windows 10 and installed Windows 11, but then I found out that my Kubuntu is no longer listed in the boot menu, and I can't find it in the BIOS either, so I'm assuming that one of the partitions I deleted was the boot partition. I looked around with several other people with bootloader issues, but none seemed to fit the situation properly enough (dual-boot with one missing after a clean install) for me to confidently give them a try.
Basically, my question is, can I recover/recreate my boot partition or add an existing partition to the current bootloader (and if so, how), can I somehow recreate my Linux install or do I need to cleanly reinstall, or is there another option?

Edit:
Here's a link to the Boot Info Summary: http://sprunge.us/NO7yCR all seems correct to me there but I have never read such a report before.

Comment: You should see the linux-partition when booting to a linux live version. From there you can start recreating/repairing the EFI boot entries. A few options are explained here: https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall

Comment: Alright I will give that a try, I presume any distro will do?

Comment: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Bootinfo summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.Lets see details, use ppa version with your USB installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Boot-Repair's default fix may work, but generally best to have someone review it and see if you really need advanced mode repairs.

Comment: @FelixJN I tried to follow the guide, but I ran into issues at step 6, as it couldn't find the required folder even though it's there, so not sure what I'm doing wrong

Comment: @oldfred I tried adding the repo, but it can't find the user yannubuntu so it fails...

Comment: If you have working Internet, the second option should work to first add ppa and then download boot-repair. Copy & paste each command. I just ran Boot-Repair that I had installed from ppa before and it worked for me. And it just updated this morning to a newer version.

Comment: @Vasilis You will have to add more details on how you fail.

Comment: @oldfred Well... I don't know what went wrong last time but now it did work, I edited the post with the link.

Comment: @FelixJN I think I didn't add the efi partition before, running it now did not give me any errors. It fixed the boot issue, but Kubuntu starts incredibly slowly and the laptop seems to power off just before it reaches the OS

Comment: Power off? I assume you have a startup animation/screen showing. Any more detailed information when pressing `ESC`? Does it boot without the thumb drive in? Did you ensure not to install the boot loader on the thumb drive?

Comment: When I force shutdown the laptop by holding the power button, you can hear some sort of "tick" as that happens and the same tick occurs during startup, as the screen goes black for a second, before the login page shows up. When pressing ESC, the startup sequence gets stuck on `dev-disk-by\x2duuid-cc26e1fa\x2de0d9\x2d49cd\x2db569\x2d61583f17bdd2,swap` I thought rebooting a few times might fix that but it did not, it takes almost two minutes atm

Comment: You should not use power button unless last recourse.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes But they have changed defaults `sudo nano /etc/sysctl.d/10-magic-sysrq.conf` Change 176 to 244 to have full set of REISUB.  Possible settings to speed up boot. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1284302/is-it-possible-to-make-ubuntu-20-04-boot-faster

Comment: I know, but it has been required in the past, generally speaking, I just recognised the sound it makes, I'm not saying I was using it here, because I wasn't. I will look into that article

Comment: It was an issue in the fstab file, which contained the UUID of the boot partition that no longer exists, I updated it to reflect the new situation and it runs like a charm again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you both oldfred and FelixJN, for pointing me in the right direction for the various aspects of my problem. I was able to recreate the EFI boot entries through a live Linux system using the guide provided by FelixJN and was then able to fix the slow boot times by fixing the UUID of the boot partition to the correct one after oldfred pointed me in the right direction.